# Documentation on FluxAggregator or OCR

Tags: chainlink

Is there any documentation on FluxAggregator or OCR? I thought the first one was properly documented previously. I would like to implement an Oracle as a POC for integration.

I was hinted at the Fluxmonitor, would I use one to query n api's and send the aggregate to a FluxAggregator contract address?

Having another process e.g. a requestor query last rounds value via the aggregators' function?

Would I use the last version v0.6?

Answer (score 0):

FluxAggregator was the aggregation contract used prior to OffChainReporting(OCR). This is why the last version with FluxAggregator is in v0.6.

For Documentation of OCR Please see
https://docs.chain.link/docs/off-chain-reporting/
and
https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/offchain-reporting/
for more information.